# How to rewrite array value?

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I have an array inside another and I would like to change a value in a key.

```
        //Obtenemos el numero de arrays
        $count = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($passer); $i++)
        {   
              if(array_key_exists($passer[1],$passer[$i])) {
              $passer[1] = "hola";
              }
             $count[] = $passer[$i];  
        }
        //return....
        return $count;
```

I need to change entries where the key is 1 and replace the value.
I have this array output:

```
array
(
     [0]=>array
          (
          [0]=>81278
          [1]=>87364
          [2]=>34923
          )
     [1]=>array
          (
          [0]=>81278
          [1]=>87364
          [2]=>34923
          )
)
```

but I get an error:

```
Warning: array_key_exists() [function.array-key-exists]:
```

Any idea what this means and what to do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things you should change. First of all the way you write your `for` statement isn't optimal, it will execute the `count()` function upon every iteration, make it like so

```
for($i = 0, $c = count($passer); $i < $c; $i++)
```

Second, your problem. You need to check the `key`, which in your case is static `1`, in the array `$passer[$i]`, so your `array_key_exists()` function should look like this

```
array_key_exists(1,$passer[$i])
```

`array_key_exists` expects the first parameter to be the `key` and second the `array` you wish to inspect

Comment: thanks, its work perfect and i modified also ` $passer[1] = "hola"; to $passer[$i][1] = "hola"; `

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to put `array_key_exists($passer[1], $passer)`

The second parameter has to be an array, but in your example  you are passing it the element of an array (which is not an array hence the php warning).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php